# Exception in thread "main" Syntax error: This module cannot be found. Java Alloy program not compiling

Tags: java, netbeans, alloy

I have written a Java program that will execute an *Alloy* (.als) file. When I am using the commandline the program works perfectly but when I try to run it using *NetBeans*, this error is shown:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" Syntax error:
> This module cannot be found.
> It is not a built-in library module, and it cannot be found at "C:\Users\brinto dibyendu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Alloy\util\integer.als".
> ```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Alloy is built & developed with Bndtools running in Eclipse. Trying to run it in Netbeans is just creating a huge amount of problems that you can avoid by taking the default route.

In Eclipse, all set up to immediately debug the main application is already done. It actually ensures resolves are handled inline instead of in another process so they are easier to debug. Then just debug it. Search for "built-in library module," and see what's happening there.

Even better, in Eclipse even the tiniest change you make to Java source code is immediately reflected in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I've found to fix this is to duplicate the .als files for the utilities in your file system.

Assuming your model (.als) file is in folder `C:\Users\brinto dibyendu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Alloy\`, you'll need to create a `util\` subdirectory in that folder and copy the source of the integer utility model (integer.als) into that subdirectory.

You can get the utility model files [here](https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/tree/master/org.alloytools.alloy.core/src/main/resources/models/util).